# Is there a function that shows parent ID for each node in CPLEX python?

Tags: cplex

Is there a function that shows parent ID for each node in CPLEX python in BranchCallback? Something like this:

```
class CB6Callback(CPX_CB.BranchCallback):  
  def __call__(self): 
                    NodeID   = self.get_node_ID()
                    ParentValue = self.get_node_data(NodeID).parent_node_ID
```